# Calculating triple integral for 3d body

Tags: integration, multivariable-calculus, multiple-integral

> We have a 3D body $G=\left \{ (x,y,z):x^2+y^2+z^2\leq a^2,0\leq z\leq\sqrt{x^2+y^2}\right \}$
>
> Defining $I_0=\iiint_G  \,dx\,dy\,dz$, $I_1=\iiint_G  z\,dx\,dy\,dz$
>
> For which $a\in\mathbb{N}$ we get that $\frac{I_1}{I_0}=\frac{3\sqrt2}{4}$?

My first step was to convert into Spherical coordinate system, thus we get that $x^2+y^2+z^2=r^2$
then $0\leq r\leq a$

and $0 \leq r\cos(\varphi) \ \leq \sqrt{(r\sin(\varphi )\cos(\theta))^2+(rsin(\varphi )sin(\theta))^2}$ from converting $0\leq z\leq\sqrt{x^2+y^2}$,

now I think I need to solve the equation for $\cos(\varphi)^2 \ = (\sin(\varphi )\cos(\theta))^2+(\sin(\varphi )sin(\theta))^2$?

$$\cos(\varphi)^2 \ = (\sin(\varphi )\cos(\theta))^2+(\sin(\varphi )\sin(\theta))^2$$
$$\cos(\varphi)^2 \ = (\cos^2(\theta)+\sin^2(\theta))\ \sin^2(\varphi)$$
$$\cos(\varphi)^2 =\sin^2(\varphi)$$
$$\tan(\varphi)=1$$
$$-\frac{\pi}{4} \leq \varphi \leq \frac{\pi}{4} $$
and for $\theta$ it's $0 \leq \theta \leq 2\pi$

So the end we have

$0\leq r\leq a$

$0 \leq \theta \leq 2\pi$

$-\frac{\pi}{4} \leq \varphi \leq \frac{\pi}{4} $

Am I correct from here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In spherical coordinates, $x = \rho \cos\theta \sin\phi, y = \rho \sin\theta \sin\phi, z = \rho \cos\phi$

Here we have $0 \leq \rho \leq a, 0 \leq \theta \leq 2\pi$. For limits of $\phi$,

Please note the lower bound of $z$ in the given condition, $0 \leq z \leq \sqrt{x^2+y^2}$

As you calculated, $2a^2\cos^2\phi = a^2 \implies \cos \phi = \pm \frac{1}{\sqrt2}, \phi = \frac{\pi}{4}, \frac{3\pi}{4}$

But as $z \geq 0, \phi \leq \frac{\pi}{2}$

So the limits of $\phi \ $ is  $ \ \frac{\pi}{4} \leq \phi \leq \frac{\pi}{2}$

$I_0 = \displaystyle \int_0^{2\pi}\int_{\pi/4}^{\pi/2}\int_0^a \rho^2 \sin\phi \ d\rho \ d\phi \ d\theta = \frac{\sqrt2  \pi  a^3}{3}$

$I_1 = \displaystyle \int_0^{2\pi}\int_{\pi/4}^{\pi/2}\int_0^a \rho^3 \sin\phi \cos \phi \ d\rho \ d\phi \ d\theta = \frac{\pi a^4}{8}$

Comment: Is this clear? Do you have any questions?

Comment: how did you get $2a^2\cos^2\phi = a^2 $?

Comment: $x^2 + y^2 \geq z^2$ so at equality, $x^2 + y^2 + z^2 = a^2$ becomes $2z^2 = a^2$ and on surface, $z = a \cos\phi$ in spherical coordinates.

Comment: In fact that part is correct in your working as well. The only thing is that $\sin^2 \phi = \cos^2\phi$ would mean $\tan \phi = \pm1$ and you get same values of $\phi$. But what you did not consider is that $z \geq 0 \implies \cos \phi \geq 0$, so $\phi \leq \frac{\pi}{2}$.